# Get coordinates of button in UIWindow coordinate's

Tags: ios, swift, coordinate

I have `UITableView` with some cells, inside those cells, I have a buttons. When I tap on the buttons, I need the coordinates of center button within UIWindow. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `UIView - convertRect:fromView:` documentation

> view : The view with rect in its coordinate system. If view is nil, this method instead converts from window base coordinates.

Try this line :

```
CGRect buttonFrame = [sender.superview convertRect:sender.frame fromView:nil];
```

This should get you the absolute button position.